# Cannot locate wp_footer() included scripts

Tags: google-analytics

Pulling my hair out here trying to locate the code being invoked by the wp_footer() hook.

The following Google Analytics code doesn't seem to be located in any of the files in my entire web directory. None of the theme files. None of the WordPress files. Nowhere to be seen.

[image: Google Analytics Code]
I realize wp_footer pulls in everything initiated by the function. It spits out a bunch of script includes among others. Everything it pulls in is fine except this one Google Analytics line, which for the life of me, doesn't seem to reside anywhere in any of the site's local files.

Searching for "GoogleAnalyticsObject", the direct "xx-xxxxxx" Google code. No keywords in that line seem to be inside any of the files. I'm not convinced the code isn't being populated from an external file, but not sure how to narrow this down to a specific function.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked your plugins?

Comment: I actually discovered the solution not too long after I posted the question. Found the answer buried in deep inside the Admin panel for customizing the particular theme that's being used. Funny, because I looked there, but missed it the first time around. Evidently, these particular theme options are saved into a database field which explains why scanning for keywords in all the site files came up null. Apparently I have to wait 2 whole days to mark my response as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer buried in deep inside the Admin panel for customizing the particular theme that's being used. Funny, because I looked there already, but missed it the first time around. Evidently, these particular options are saved into a database which explains why scanning for keywords found in all the site files came up null.